# calculate approximate local time using longitude in hive / sql

Tags: sql, hive, timezone, timestamp, latitude-longitude

I have a table in hive with timestamps (2017-12-12 18:54:03.0) and latitudes/longitudes  (e.g. -75.85506)

How can I convert these to approximate local times in hive?   I don't need it to be completely accurate - I'm sure daylight savings time makes it tricky

Edit:  I need to do this in hive - I see answers in other languages.

Comment: this is not a duplicate - i need to do this in hive.

Comment: Hive does not have such functionality directly, but it if it did it should be put on the list in the dup answer.  Instead, you'll need to use the lat/lon data from outside of hive with one of the techniques listed in the dup answer.  Put the resulting IANA time zone string (ex `America/Los_Angeles`) into another field in hive.  Then you can use Hive's `from_utc_timestamp` function to convert the time stamp from UTC to the local time of the given time zone.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Hive's ability to call a Java function from within a query, such as with [ReflectUDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ReflectUDF).  Again, that Java function would have to use one of the techniques listed in the dup answer.